# Oracle - PL/SQL: How to read from changeable file names in external tables?

Tags: oracle, plsql, external-tables

I need help please. I want to create a table using PL/SQL that contains sysdate in its name? For example, table_name_sysdate?

I am trying to create an external table that will read from a .csv file and the file name I want to read from, its name consists of constant (table_name) and the date (sysdate). This file name is changeable daily according to the date. I don't know how to create the mechanism to load from daily changeable file names.

This is my code, I don't know what to put inside the brackets with question marks.

```
create table ext_table_1
(med_name varchar2(20),
cost integer)
organization external
(type ORACLE_LOADER 
default directory orders
access parameters
(records delimited by newline
fields terminated by ',')
location (???)
reject limit 200;
```

Answer (score 3):

The file is specified in the LOCATION property of the table.  You can change it with an `alter table` statement, like this:

```
 alter table log_files location ('prefix_20121219.csv');
```

So basically, create the table with today's file and then just run the ALTER TABLE statement each day, in a scheduled job or similar operation.

Alternatively, you can keep the file name static and rename/copy each day's file to that name.  If you're running on 11gR2 you can associate a pre-processor file - a shell script - to do this whenever you query the external table.  [Find out more](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=513).

Answer (score 1):

That's a reference to a directory object, create with "create directory".

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_5007.htm

Comment: I know what to put there but the file name is changeable according to the current date. I don't know how to make it read files automatically that are named as the following (file_DD_MM_YY)

Comment: OK, I understand. You can issue an "alter table" command each day to modify the file name that it is to read from, since the file name is deterministically based on the system date

Comment: There must be a way to do it automatically. Thanks for trying to help me anyway. Much appreciated. God bless you.

Comment: You can automate it through DBMS_Scheduler

Comment: Another option would be to use the preprocessor, which is a unix script that runs prior to the file being read. So if you can write unix script to find the correct file, this is the technique for you.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you want is to load from external CSV file into a table, and the filename contains a timestamp, so it's name changes everytime.
An external script could simply copy that file (extract the timestamp from the filename and check if that matches today in the right format) to a standard name, the load script expects. If you need the original file later, before overwriting, first make a copy of the file in a backup directory.